# Have a greater number than 256 android file output stream

Tags: java, android, io

I am using `fos.write(some_number)`
but when I am trying to display that number then it won't be greater than 255.

This is the second activity's code:

```
        FileOutputStream fos;
        try {
            fos = openFileOutput("Income", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
//"Income" is the number that is written on the TextField
            fos.write(Income);
            fos.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

First activity's code:

```
try {
        FileInputStream fis;
        fis = openFileInput("Income");
        TOTAL_INCOME = fis.read();
        fis.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    //...
    //....


  TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.IncomeValue);
  textView.setText(""+ TOTAL_INCOME);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [write()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html#write-int-) method only writes a byte which has a range 0-255, so you won't get anything more than that.

Better use [DataOutputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html) and [DataInputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html) like:

```
FileOutputStream fos;
try {
fos = openFileOutput("Income", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(fos);
dos.writeInt(Income);
dos.close();
fos.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

And 1st Activity:

```
try {
FileInputStream fis;
fis = openFileInput("Income");
DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(fis);
TOTAL_INCOME = dis.readInt();
dis.close();
fis.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.IncomeValue);
textView.setText(""+ TOTAL_INCOME);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the javadoc for [`FileOutputStream#write()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html#write-int-) you'll notice that it only writes out a single byte, which has the range 0-255, inclusive. That's why you'll never see numbers larger than 255.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can you tell me a way to be able to save numbers greater than 255?

Comment: You can't directly, as `FileOutputStream` operates directly on the bytes of the file. You'll need to figure out how to store/retrieve multiple bytes at once so you can represent numbers with larger ranges.